# Bug? Numerical calculation error with FullSimplify and arbitrary precision

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, numerics, arbitrary-precision

**Bug introduced after 5.2, fixed in 8.0, reintroduced in 9.0 and persisting through 12.3**

---

Is this a bug?

If I do

```
FullSimplify[n E^(0``10 n)]
```

then it returns

```
n/2
```

which is obviously incorrect.

(I've simplified the example, following a comment.)

[*Mathematica* Version 10.3.1.0]

Comment: A wild guess: Since the ``-1.`10`` in `a`, `b`, and `nb` are independent, the quotient has a great deal of uncertainty in `nb/a`, represented by ```0``9.698970004336022```.  Consider ```Plot[MinMax[1.`10.*2.`10.^(Interval[0``9.698970004336022] n) n ]/
  n, {n, -10^10, 10^10}]```.  But I don't understand the `1/2` for a point estimate of the coefficient, or why `b/a` is presented as an exact result.  Note that `a/a` is not `1` exactly.

Comment: Simpler example: `FullSimplify[n E^(0``100. n) ]`, `Series[n E^(0``100. n) , {n, 0, 0}]`.  The accuracy `100.` does not seem to matter, big or small, positive or negative.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't a bug. `n/2` just isn't correct.  Can you please contact Wolfram Support and let us know what they said?

Comment: With versions 5.2 and 8.0.4 I get `E^(0.*10^-10 n) n` as the output (with `InputForm` being `E^(0``10.*n)*n`). So the bug was introduced in version 9.0.

Comment: Sorry to say, but with version **7.0.1** on Win7x64 I get **n/2**. Incredible.

Comment: The same bug on `MMA 11.3`  Incredible.

Comment: There is a workaround: `FullSimplify[Rationalize[n E^(0``10 n)]]` performs `n`.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've traced down the problem.  It hinges on two things. An identity:

```
Cosh[x] == Sinh[2 x]/(2 Sinh[x]) // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

And a questionable auto-simplification:

```
Csch[0``10. n] Sinh[2 0``10. n]
(*  1  *)

{Csch[0``10. n], Sinh[2 0``10. n]} // FullForm
(*  List[Csch[Times[0``10.,n]],Sinh[Times[0``9.698970004336019,n]]]  *)
```

(The coefficients are equal, so I guess that's why they are treated as identical.)

Here are the steps in which these problems arise:

```
n Exp@(0``10 n) // ExpToTrig
(*  n (Cosh[0.*10^-10 n] + Sinh[0.*10^-10 n])  *)

n (Cosh[0``10. n] + Sinh[0``10. n]) //. SimplifyDump`CosToSinRules
(*  n (1/2 + Sinh[0.*10^-10 n])  *)

Sinh[0``10. n] // FullSimplify
(*  0  *)
```

The simplified expression is already wrong in the second step, in which the identity is applied.  The last step is questionable, too, but understandable.  It's what leads to `n/2` as the answer.

I, for one, feel I understand why this bug has persisted.

Maybe the best workaround is to flush all "underflowed" arbitrary-precision numbers to exact `0`:

```
FullSimplify[n E^(0``10 n) /. z_ /; z == 0 :> 0]
(*  n  *)
```